# Inject scope of a function into JSON.parse

Tags: json, node.js

I have a bunch of JSON files that I need to parse (in node), but many of the files have things like this:

```
"_id" : NumberLong(528000021)
```

Where `NumberLong` is a function out of scope of the JSON file.  When I run JSON.parse I get an error (understandably) that it found an unexpected token.  Is there a way to create a function NumberLong and inject it into the scope of the parse?

--EDIT--

Gave @Svabael the answer karma on this one, but for the curious here is how I ended up solving the problem.  I created GLOBAL functions for any function appearing in the "JSON", and then created a module then required it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');

GLOBAL.ISODate = function(x){return x};
GLOBAL.NumberLong = function(x){return x};

var source = "./JSONFiles/";
var target = "./JSONModules/";

for(var i=2;i<process.argv.length;i++) {
    var fn = process.argv[i];

    var sn = source + fn;
    var sd = fs.readFileSync(sn,'utf8');

    var tn = target + fn.replace('.json','.js');
    var td = "module.exports = " + sd;

    fs.writeFileSync(tn,td);

    var json = require(tn);

    //json now has the data

}
```

To call the script above it is a bash one-liner:

```
ls JSONFiles | xargs ./json2modules.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a valid JSON:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(528000021)
}
```

This is a valid JSON:

```
{
    "_id" : "NumberLong(528000021)"
}
```

I think that you are trying to parse a javascript object and the error that you have is normal. If this is the case, then you don't need to parse it at all.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that, but was hoping for a shortcut :)  I'm going to just turn them all into modules and do a dynamic require.